# Ruby 1.9.1 installed, however Ruby --version shows different version

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, ubuntu-12.04

I installed ruby via

```
apt-get install ruby1.9.1 rubygems
```

However, when I run `ruby --version` I see

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

Have I missed something? When I try to run a gem which requires 1.9+ it fails and asks me to upgrade.

Comment: what ruby version manager you use?

Comment: @Monk_Code he doesn't use one, he installed from the Ubuntu repos.

Answer (score 0):

The package `ruby1.9.1` will give you an executable called `ruby1.9.1`, which you should use instead of `ruby`.

Comment: So how do I go about replacing the built in `ruby` with `ruby1.9.1`? I just need it to run this gem I'm trying to use but it requires 1.9+.

Answer (score 0):

You can set ruby1.9.1 as default ruby version using following command

```
update-alternatives --set ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
```

You may find out about available alternatives using following

```
update-alternatives --query ruby
```

Comment: After doing that, `gem --version` still shows 1.8. How do I change that too?

Comment: @BenedictLewis what is the version of your gem? if you want to change your gem`s version you can try update gem with following command:

`gem update --system [version number of gem which you want to upgrade]`

Answer (score 0):

In this way you can set the default ruby version

```
   $ rvm --default use 1.9.2

   $ ruby -v

   ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]
```